# Is is bad to implement NodeJS on the backend and use Node Child Process to run python? project: Algorithmic trader. Should I use just Django?

Tags: python, node.js, django, api, algorithmic-trading

I am highly experienced with NodeJS, but not Python or Django. I want to manipulate API's in JS, but do all computational tasks in Python. Is this a good way to go about it, or should I take the time to learn django, and utilize that as my full-stack framework.

Comment: This is probably opinion based. Still, I'd probably go with Node.js and calling Python. It's overall simpler - less you have to learn and it's faster to get a working version. All development will be faster, too. Doing all in Django might not offer enough benefits to offset the time to get up to speed with Python+Django. Which, admittedly, probably won't be *that* long but still longer than not having to do it. On the other hand, if you want more Python+Django experience for the future, go for it.

Comment: thanks for the input! I agree with you, just didn't know if I would be facing performance issues or something, since I am not experienced with python and django.

Comment: That's typically an "opinion-based" question - and as a matter of fact, I totally disagree with VLAZ's comment - unless your computations are long-running jobs that will have to run off-band (via an async task queue) of course. You _will_ have to learn Python anyway to write those part, so learning a Python web framework is not a lot of work - and there are much lighter things than Django (Flask comes to mind), specially if you don't need the whole Django shebang. My 2 cents...